# docker-compose mongodb fresh instance not working

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

Trying to bring docker-compose up with the following:

```
    version: '3.1'

    services:
      mongo:
        image: mongo
        container_name: mongo-db
        networks:
          - mongo
        restart: always
        environment:
          MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_ROOT_USER}
          MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
          MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: ${MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE}
        ports:
          - 27017:27017
        volumes:
          - ./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
      mongo-express:
        image: mongo-express:latest
        container_name: mongo-express
        restart: always
        networks:
          - mongo
        depends_on:
          - mongo
        ports:
          - 8081:8081
        environment:
          ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongo
          ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT: 27017
          ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: ${MONGO_ROOT_USER}
          ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: ${MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
```

The entry point js file as below:

```
db.createUser(
    {
        user: "dba",
        pwd: "dba",
        roles: [
            {
                role: "readWrite",
                db: "mydb"
            }
        ]
    }
);
```

The variables are defined in .env file as below:

```
MONGO_ROOT_USER=root
MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=mydb
MONGOEXPRESS_LOGIN=dev
MONGOEXPRESS_PASSWORD=dev
```

When I login to mongo-express, I don't see the user or the db that is created by mongo-init.js
Also, I can't login if I try to connect using:

```
docker exec -it mongo-db mongo --username dba
```

However, if I use the following I can connect but still don't see mydb when I run show dbs:

```
docker exec -it mongo-db mongo --username root
```

What's happening here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js
Successfully added user: {
        "user" : "dba",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "mydb"
                }
        ]
}


killing process with pid: 30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change the env to:

```
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME  
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

> These variables, used in conjunction, create a new user and set that
>   user's password. This user is created in the admin authentication
>   database and given the role of root, which is a "superuser" role.

see the [Docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo)

**another note:**

if you do not insert data with your JavaScript files, then no database is created.

> MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE
>
> This variable allows you to specify the name of a database to be used
>   for creation scripts in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*.js (see
>   Initializing a fresh instance below). MongoDB is fundamentally
>   designed for "create on first use", so if you do not insert data with
>   your JavaScript files, then no database is created.

Comment: same result. I updated both entries in .env and changed the variables in Dockercompose.yml to use MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_* for mongo and mongo-express. I got the same results

Comment: Thanks. I just added the following to the beginning of the init js file: db.createCollection("empty");